# C#: Add "Select" item to Dynamic Fill ComboBox method

Tags: c#, methods, combobox, void

I need to add "Select" at index 0 without know DataTable columns count or name because this method in DataAccessLayer and will use later`

```
// ComboBox Fill Method
public static void ComboBoxFill(ComboBox cbo, string Query, string cboDisplayMember, string cboValueMember)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
                cbo.DataSource = dt;
                cbo.DisplayMember = cboDisplayMember;
                cbo.ValueMember = cboValueMember;
                cbo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)cbo.DataSource;
            int columns =  dt.Columns.Count;
            int rows = dt.Rows.Count;

Comment: How can i use int columns and rows after declare it ?

Comment: You posting is a little unclear.  Wan't sure if you were asking How to select the ComboBox, or How to update/insert data.  So I was assuming you wanted to change the data.  The correct way of changing data is to modify the DataTable.  You also said you didn't know the columns or count so I got the columns and count from cbo.

Comment: Thanks, It has been solved and i have added the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by the following code.
Thanks for all ...

```
     public static void ComboBoxFill(ComboBox cbo, string Query, string cboDisplayMember, string cboValueMember)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count ; i++)
        {
            if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == cboDisplayMember)
            {
                drow[i] = "Select";
            }
            else if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == cboValueMember)
            {
                drow[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                drow[i] = null;
            }
        }

        dt.Rows.InsertAt(drow, 0);

        cbo.DataSource = dt;
        cbo.DisplayMember = cboDisplayMember;
        cbo.ValueMember = cboValueMember;
        cbo.SelectedIndex = 0;
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put this line in your ComboBoxFill() function.

```
public static void ComboBoxFill(ComboBox cbo, string Query, string cboDisplayMember, string cboValueMember)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
                cbo.DataSource = dt;

                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow[0] = "Select";
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);

                cbo.DisplayMember = cboDisplayMember;
                cbo.ValueMember = cboValueMember;
                cbo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                con.Close();
            }
```

It will add "Select" at postion 0

Comment: Error: Additional information: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set

Comment: Showing error because unknown column name and columns count. But it has been solved by For

Comment: Thanks, It has been solved and i have added the solution